# SonicWall DMZ and LAN inbound mapping

Tags: routing, wan, sonicwall, lan

I have a question, to which I think I know the answer.
I have a SonicWall TZ 215 configured and working fine with a DMZ and ports mapped through to that DMZ, but the need has come up to map traffic through to a system on the LAN network. 
When I configured the NAT Rules exactly the same as the ones I have for the DMZ no traffic was allowed through to the LAN.
So, my guess is when you have a DMZ configured, that you can only allow traffic through to that, because lets face it, mapping through to your LAN isn't the smartest thing to do.
Here are some details.

WAN1 11.11.11.11

WAN2 22.22.22.22

LAN 192.192.192.192

DMZ 193.193.193.193

FTP Traffic mapped through from WAN2 to DMZ address 193.193.193.X

My added configuration was

HTTP Traffic from WAN1 (Or all WAN) to LAN address 192.192.192.X

This just wouldn't work. Suggestions, assistance, help greatly received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should work fine.  Did you add a firewall rule in addition to the NAT policy?  You'll need to allow  HTTP traffic from "Any" to "WAN Interface IP" (for both)

Comment: Thank you. I did a reset and re-configure and everything worked. It is possible I miss clicked something the first time. Never do firewall work when you are tired! :-)